# throw err/MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am having this issue when trying to run `node index.js` in my terminal on VSC.

This is the error,

```
[Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS Z:\01 Code notes> node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'Z:\01 Code notes\index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)        
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
PS Z:\01 Code notes> ][1]
```

I have tried so many different things. I tried all the suggested fixes on these pages,
[Node MODULE_NOT_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083351/node-module-not-found)

[Why does VsCode NPM throw a module not found error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974185/why-does-vscode-npm-throw-a-module-not-found-error)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65893

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've had issues in the past with certain type of folder names that node doesn't like.  I would try renaming the folder without the spaces.

Comment: I tried it locally and wasn't able to reproduce it, but I know it has happened.  Is there a node_modules folder in there?  It looks like your taking a course, sometimes the class will have the package.json, but you need to run "npm install" to install any of the dependency packages.

Answer (score 0):

That means you are using a module that you haven't installed, check your code.

Comment: Z:\01 Code notes\index.js, look at the file where you are using this "module"